# Recursive loop with a user input variable

Tags: excel, recursion, vba

I am having a issue running a recursive search for some text in multiple files in multiple folders. The code below  is what I have so far. The two cases are to help limit the search. The problem comes when I am trying to get the text to search for from the user. I am unable to pass the variable to the other sub. The way it is setup below, the editor gives me an error when I am calling the getfiles sub recursively (I assume because I am unable to use "call" by the way the error reads).

If I take out the second variable, "theString", as a passed variable and hard code something into the getfiles sub, this works great. If I try to ask the question in the getfiles sub, it pops up over and over, since it is recursive.

Is there a way to ask the question and pass the variable to the loop?

```
Sub somesub()

    Dim theComp As String

    Comp = InputBox("Enter 1 for CDL or 2 for MDF.", "Company")

    Select Case Comp

    Case Is = 1
        theComp = "CDL"
    Case Is = 2
        theComp = "MDF"
    End Select

    theString = InputBox("Enter the accession #", "Accession")

   path = "F:\Finance & Accounting\Revenue Services\HL7 archive\2015\" & theComp
     Call getfiles(path, theString)

End Sub

Sub getfiles(ByVal path As String, ByVal theString As String)

    Dim fso As Object
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim folder As Object
        Set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)
    Dim subfolder As Object
    Dim file As Object
    Dim path2 As String

    theString2 = theString

    Do While path <> ""
        For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders
            **getfiles (subfolder.path, theString2)**
        Next subfolder
        For Each file In folder.Files
            path2 = file.path
            Set filestuff = fso.OpenTextFile(path2)
            Do While Not filestuff.AtEndOfLine
                line = filestuff.ReadLine
                If InStr(1, line, theString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    Debug.Print path2
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        Next file

        filestuff.Close
        Set fso = Nothing
        Set folder = Nothing
        Set subfolder = Nothing
        Set file = Nothing
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: can you provide the error message? because your code works for me

Comment: The parentheses around the arguments shouldn't be there - use either: `getfiles  subfolder.path, theString2` or `Call getfiles(subfolder.path, theString2)` Not sure if that is the actual reason for the error though. Also, there's no declaration for the variable `path` used in `somesub`

Comment: h3n - I am not even able to run the code as written above. The line getfiles (subfolder.path, theString2) is red and I get an error that says "Compile error: Expected =".

Comment: I followed barrowc's advice and the code now runs. It allows me to enter all variables and will print out the correct file name. However, after a while it spits out a "Runtime 91 error - Object variable or With block variable not set" and stops on the "For Each subfolder...." line. Is it the variable "path" in the While statement or the variable "subfolder" that is having a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a few problems that could be causing the error.

First, you need to move the filestuff.close line into the for each file loop, just before the "next file".  That way, you close each file after you're done with it.  In the current code, each file gets left open -- not certain whether VBA will automatically close them for you or if these are getting orphaned.

Second, is the Do/While loop.  What exactly are you trying to do there?  If you're looking for "theString" only in the first line of the text file, then get rid of the loop, just read the first line, look for the match, write the outpt if a match, close the file, and repeat the For Each loop.  If you're looking for "theString" in the entire file, then I think you need "Do While Not filestuff.AtEndOfStream" instead of endofline.

Addendum:

OK, here's the real problem:

You call getfiles with your root path.  That then calls getfiles for the first subfolder, and then the first subfolder, etc, until you get to a bottom folder.  A folder with no further subfolders.

The call to getfiles skips over the subfolder loop because there's no subfolders.  Then it loops over the file loop, and all is good.  Once all the files are processed, the loop exits.  All of your objects are set to nothing.

And then what happens?  The LOOP statement hits the end, and checks back to see if path<>"".  Which it doesn't (since path is still the same).  So the loop repeats, and tries the subfolder check again.  But now, all of your objects are set to nothing.  So it fails.

The solution?  Get rid of the Do/Loop for the path<>"".  You never need to loop here -- you first loop all of the subfolders, and then loop all of the files.  Once you do that, you're done.  set the objects to nothing, and end the sub.  The recursion will drop you back to the next higher level, and continue.

Comment: I had wondered about the file closing. I added your steps above, however I am still getting the same error. Like I said, the macro is finding what it should be finding, but it is having some problem with getting out of the For Each Subfolder loop.

Comment: Fixed my answer.  The problem is the outer Do/Loop for path<>"".  You don't need it.